# Custom complex body shape with cut feature

Tags: opengl, android, libgdx, mesh

I need to create sprites (or scene2d actors or whatever) with custom shape, preferably generated from a png image (marching squares?).

I followed some Mesh tutorials but they all hardcode the triangularized-shape vertices in an array, which is completely insane.

I will later have to give my sprite a *cut* feature, like [this game.](http://duckiedeck.com/play/cut-out)
so I'll have to regenerate and redraw a new shape several times. Some told me to review the Drawable classes as well as Mesh, and create my own MeshDrawable that renders using meshes.

Do you have an idea of how to dynamically generate vertices and shapes instead of hardcoding coordinates?

at what level will my Mesh be responding to touch events and reacting with the user?

Any clarification will be welcome, I'm kind of lost.